New Duralast Gold Rotors and Pads vibrate badly right before stopping BEFORE BEDDING
Honda Fit 2011
Just replaced the calipers, rotors, and pads on my front brakes using Duralast Gold rotors and pads. I have bled the brakes.  The rotors have a coating (not oil) that is supposed to wear off on the contact points but remain on the rest of the rotor.  Instructions say some extra noise is expected until this is worn off.
I just reversed the car out of the garage and brakes engage fine but right before it stops, the front brakes vibrate violently.  I haven't bedded in the brakes yet.  I want to be sure this is normal for the Duralast Gold rotors before I take it out on the road and bed in the brakes.  Happens going forward as well.
I also just thought: Any chance this is the ABS sensor?  I ordered a Foxwell NT510 OBD scanner that should be here today, so I'll be able to check if something is wrong.  No ABS light on currently.
UPDATE:  I'm going to flush the brake fluid through all 4 brakes in the order specified by Honda.  I really needed to flush it anyways, so I'll see if this shows any air.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

I ended up bleeding the ABS and the brake lines.  I took it out to bed the brakes and it did take 5-6 quick brakes from 55mph to get them smooth, but now they are great.
After 2-3 brakes during bedding, they started pulling to the left so I thought I messed something up, but by the end, the.brakes stopped evenly.
